# How to get value from Javascript popup call in MVC ActionResult ?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript function that calls a MVC action result which in turn will populate the correct View. I need to pass .Net code with that pop up call, is it possible?

So for example I need to pass a integer from the model over so I can use it in my action result.

a button click calls this function

```
 ShowPopUp = function () {
    window.showModalDialog("/FileUpload/GetPopupData", "wndPopUp", "width=300,height=500");
}
```

and here is the action result

```
 public ActionResult GetPopupData()
    {
        //Call the pop up view and populate it accordingly
        return new GetDocumentTypeAction<ActionResult>
        {
            OnLoaded = m => View("../../Areas/Exports/Views/FileUpload/FileUpload", m),
            OnErrorOccured = (m) => Redirects.ToErrorPage()
        }.Execute(GtsClient);
    }
```

How will I send the int over and how will I read it in the action result?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, render out the integer you want from the model as a JavaScript variable that you can reference in your ShowPopUp() function.

```
<script>
var viewId = <%=Model.ViewId%>;

ShowPopUp = function () {
    window.showModalDialog("/FileUpload/GetPopupData/" + viewId, 
    "wndPopUp", "width=300,height=500");
} 
</script>
```